# The `idiv` instruction generates incorrect remainder in RDX. Why?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, integer-division

I want to calculate the remainder of a signed division, but the `idiv` instruction generates an incorrect result.
I'm trying to calculate " -1 mod 20 ".

I wrote this :

```
mov  rdx , 0
mov  rax , -1
mov  rbx , 20
idiv rbx
mov  rbx, rdx       ; move remainder to rbx
```

After running this code, RBX should be 19 but after seeing result in gdb, RBX equals 0xF (15 in decimal). Why?

Comment: Because you zeroed `rdx`. You want to set that to `-1` as well (or sign extend after loading `rax`). Remember that `rdx` holds the top 64 bits of the dividend. As it is, you calculated `(2^64-1) / 20`  which indeed gives a remainder of 15. Note that for negative numbers you will get negative remainders, due to truncation towards zero so it will be `-1` not `19`.

Comment: ok . i add "cqo" instruction after loading rax . but the result is still wrong . the remainder was -1

Comment: oh . how can i convert -1 to 19 ?

Comment: Add the divisor, `20` in this case. Note that will convert `0` to `20` which is probably not what you want. You might should do it conditionally.

Comment: You could move `20-1` into `rdx` instead of `-1` if `rax` is negative. That way you should get a positive remainder.

Comment: @chtz - that doesn't seem to work. Try the simple case of -20 mod 20.

Comment: idiv remainder is zero or has the same sign as the dividend. In math, modulo is zero or has the same sign as the divisor. If using idiv, if the remainder is not zero, and has the opposite sign as the divisor, then add the divisor to the remainder.